# File permissions while installing gems using chef_gem

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra

Installed `simple-graphite` gem using `chef_gem` resource on a Vagrant box and a VM machine both Ubuntu. But the file permissions on the `gemspec` and `gem` file installed on both the machines are different.

Under `/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1` `gems` and `specifications` directory

**Vagrant Box**

    `drwxrwx---  4 root root 4096 Dec  4 14:58 simple-graphite-2.1.0`


    `-rw-rw---- 1 root root 1181 Dec  4 14:58 simple-graphite-2.1.0.gemspec`

**VM Machine**

    `drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec  4 15:55 simple-graphite-2.1.0`


    `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1181 Dec  4 15:55 simple-graphite-2.1.0.gemspec`

**From the Vagrant box**

    `vagrant:/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1$ getfacl specifications/
    file: specifications/
    owner: root
    group: root
    user::rwx
    group::r-x
    other::r-x`


    `vagrant:/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1$ getfacl gems
    file: gems
    owner: root
    group: root
    user::rwx
    group::r-x
    other::r-x`

Is there a reason or a setting which is causing the difference in access permissions for `others` on Vagrant box. There seem to be no attribute in `chef_gem` to set a permission during the gem install. Any pointers on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Using vagrant chef is run through sudo, on your vm you're probabaly running it as root directly which may end up with different UMASK for file creations. (This is just a guess, without more information on your images, it sounds hard to found)

Comment: Thanks Tensibai. I checked running chef-client on both machines using `` sudo `` and the permissions are set as described earlier.

Comment: So check if there's a different umask on both machine something like `grep -ri umask /etc/*` should be a start. I really think the difference is at OS level more than in chef (chef_gem does not set permissions on gems files, so it's probably an OS behavior on permission inheritance).

Comment: Thanks again. The vagrant box was where chef server is installed and looks like the .chef/knife.rb file includes an umask - File.umask(0007) and that seems to be causing the difference. I am wondering where the umask is set on the chef client nodes.

Comment: As far as I know I would say /etc/profile, if you don't specify it in client.rb or in the user profile running chef, there's no reason for it to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef is just running `gem install`, so unless there are variations in umask this is likely not something you can control.

Comment: Thanks @coreranger. We are using `knife.rb` during the `chef-client` run and it includes a `File.umask(0007)` by default which is causing the difference in the permissions. Once the `File.umask` to `0003` all the users get `read` permission. Can we set the default to `0003` in `knife.rb` instead of `0007` so that all the users of `chef` will not face this issue.